# Is this question about recommending .onion sites on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Question of-the topic:

https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/292/any-good-onion-sites-that-are-safe-and-interesting

> The title says it all! Do you guys know any good/interesting .onion domains? I really wanna start exploring again. Haven't been there since 2011

I quoted the question so it will be here for reference after it gets deleted.

My gut reaction when I saw it was to look for the flag button, but I don't see any discussion about it here yet. So I thought we should come to an official consensus about it.

Comment: Your example question is very vague.  However recommendation could be ask like : "Any good .onion sites that are safe and interesting?" or "Is there a site that allow me sync a directory between several computer".  The first question is too broad and option-based.  I don't think the second question is.  I think question about recommending .onion site should be accepted only when they are very specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any question of this type that asks for web resources or sites about a general topic is a good candidate for closing through either of these reasons:

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

On topic or not, it's too opinion based. I'd recommend a vote to close for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think that kind of questions is **off-topic**. They have a lot of possible answers and are based on user's opinion - should be closed, we're not making a resource of .onion addresses and opinions about them.

> **Too broad**
>
> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
> too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
> or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.